# connect DASHBOARD to NODE-RED

Tags: json, node-red, freeboard

I have an external Freeboard Dashboard that I need to talk to a remote Node-Red server.  Using the built in Node-Red-Dashboard is not an option.

I cannot get Freeboard to recognize the Node-Red server as a JSON source.  I have made sure my Freeboard installation works by using http://ip.jsontest.com.

I have checked the header and output of the Node-Red server but still no luck.

| Node-Red Header: http://10.0.3.3:1880/hello | http://ip.jsontest.com |
| --- | --- |
| HTTP/1.1 200 OK | HTTP/1.1 200 OK |
| X-Powered-By: Express | Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * |
| Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 | Content-Type: application/json |
| Content-Length: 16 | X-Cloud-Trace-Context: c4378d0107d5df3af2613... |
| ETag: W/"10-zPVCxAyElRj7W5BuknPouQ" | Content-Length: 23 |
| Date: Mon, 17 May 2021 14:41:34 GMT | Date: Mon, 17 May 2021 14:43:02 GMT |
| Connection: keep-alive | Server: Google Frontend |

**Node-Red Page Source:**
{"Signal" : "3"}

**ip.jsontest.com Page Source:**
{"ip": "99.140.82.10"}

Help.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "External Freeboard Dashboard"? Where is Freeboard running compared to where Node-RED is running?

Comment: What I mean by external is a separate server from node-red.  Node-red has its own dashboard but I don't want to use that.